# Play 2.5-SwaggerUI

Tags: java, playframework, swagger-ui

I am using play 2.5 in our project and made configuration 
as this process  http://swagger.io/playing-with-swagger-using-swagger-and-swagger-ui-with-the-play-framework/

When  I am trying to open the http://localhost:9000/api-docs/api/todos
the below error is prompting  in my logs kindly let me know do I have to do any extra  configuration for this:

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[AbstractMethodError:
>   controllers.ApiHelpController$.play$api$mvc$Results$*setter*$PaymentRequired_$eq(Lplay/api/mvc/Results$Status;)V]]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992546/175554 may help