# Play Framework Swagger UI Integration Error

Tags: playframework-2.0, swagger

I'm trying to integrate Swagger UI for the Rest API which is served by Play Framework 2.5.x

I did the following:

1. Included the following dependencies in my build.sbt

> ```
>   "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.3"
>   "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0-4"
>   "org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "2.2.0"
> ```

2. Added the following to my routes:

> ```
> GET         /swagger.json                controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
> GET         /docs/                       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/swagger-ui",file="index.html")
> GET         /docs/*file                  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/swagger-ui",file)
> ```

3. I then try accessing the swagger.json

Here is the error that I get:

```
[error] application -

! @77515gnlp - Internal server error, for (GET) [/swagger.json] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at play.modules.swagger.ApiListingCache$$anonfun$listing$1.apply(ApiListingCache.scala:15)
    at play.modules.swagger.ApiListingCache$$anonfun$listing$1.apply(ApiListingCache.scala:11)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at play.modules.swagger.ApiListingCache$.listing(ApiListingCache.scala:11)
    at controllers.SwaggerBaseApiController.getResourceListing(ApiHelpController.scala:128)
    at controllers.ApiHelpController$$anonfun$getResources$1.apply(ApiHelpController.scala:74)
    at controllers.ApiHelpController$$anonfun$getResources$1.apply(ApiHelpController.scala:71)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:371)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:370)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:498)
```

Is there anything else that I should be adding or looking into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your project a while more I figured out what is the issue you are facing. Basically the Play Swagger Module provides a **Guice** binding to initialise itself which you do not seem to use in your library so the module can not initialise itself and then you get an error at runtime. I will report this as an issue to PlaySwagger (should be written in the docs).

What happens exactly is:

1. When instantiating a new server, Play will initialise Guice
2. Guice will look for any module to do its dependency injection
3. Guice will inject `SwaggerPlugin` (of Play Swagger) https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/blob/master/play-2.6/swagger-play2/app/play/modules/swagger/SwaggerModule.scala#L11
4. Server is started
5. The `http://localhost:9000/swagger.json` GET request is processed
6. Swagger Play looks for API metadata but this was never set https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/blob/master/play-2.6/swagger-play2/app/play/modules/swagger/ApiListingCache.scala#L14
7. The method called by Swagger Play tries to access a `null` static variable of Swagger Core library, Swagger API https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/1.5/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/config/ScannerFactory.java#L4

**So why is that variable null?**

*Well, the Play Swagger library relies on the Java lib Swagger Core, so when setting up it will assign a value to the static method thus expecting that variable to be set a runtime.*

**What went wrong?**

*Unfortunately PlaySwagger, like Play relies on Guice and Swagger Java lib, bringing the problems of the Java language: static variables and null pointer exceptions. Also it relies on OpenAPI 2 instead of the more recent OpenAPI 3.*

**What do I suggest?**

*Maybe try using iHeartRadio's Swagger, at first sight it seems to be more lightweight and not using Guice. Also from my experience I prefer that it uses yml comments on the `routes` file instead of annotations, this can prevent compile and runtime errors to the whole app but it makes the debugging more difficult as it will just fail to silently generate the `swagger.json` file. I suggest you try to use the alternative installation to generate the `swagger.json` at runtime. Link: https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger/blob/master/docs/AlternativeSetup.md*

Good luck, hope that was helpful.

Comment: On a side note that actually meant that the plugin is not initialised and the other answer is also valid to other people having that problem.

Answer (score 4):

You seems to have not enabled the swagger module in your `application.conf`:

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule"
```

I recommend you to refer to this great blog post for a correct swagger integration with the play framework: [Medium article](https://sahebmotiani.medium.com/swagger-with-play-all-you-need-to-know-d9147089d990)

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried recreating a project and just added the endpoint and dependencies. I notice your same error but after adding the config it got fixed by it. Could you please add more information or example of a project?

Comment: referenced link is dead

Comment: fixed link. @slashdottir as explained in the link, this reference may now be outdated. I still hope this answer may be helpful though.